# Deserialized value of transient int?

Tags: java, serialization

```
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable
{
 public String name;
 public int transient id;
}
```

---

Suppose we are serializing ...

```
Employee e = new Employee();
e.name="REUBEN";
e.id=94731;
```

---

Now if I deserialize this then

```
System.out.println("Name: " + e.name); will give the o/p REUBEN
System.out.println("ID: " + e.id); will give the o/p 0
```

It is clear that as `id` is `transient`  it was not sent to the output stream.

My question is, this zero is the default value of `int` ?
We are not saving the state so it is giving the output as `0` ,  but it is also a value. Shouldn't it be `null` ?

Comment: Yes. But I wouldn't recommend relying on it to be `0` (conceptually, it is an uninitialized variable).

Comment: Your example is very bad.  The transient modifier indicates that a field should not be considered part of the object's permanent state.  id is usually an important part of an Employee's permanent state.

Comment: what emory said, and @Mechanical, it's zero by the spec, so no worries

Comment: ints can't be null. Your question is meaningless.

Comment: @Mechanical snail the zero is specified in the JLS. You can rely on it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, member variables of a class get their default values when they come into being (when they are created in a a JVM) hence the 0, which is the default value of the primitive `int` type. If this is causing problems with "verifying" whether the ID was sent across or not, just use `Integer` which would get the default value of `null` (not that it should be a source of any confusion, just saying).

```
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable
{
 public String name;
 public transient Integer id;
}
System.out.println("Name: " + e.name); will give the o/p REUBEN
System.out.println("ID: " + e.id); will give the o/p null
```

Answer (score 7):

It can't be null, because `int` is a primitive type. Instead, it receives the default value for the type, which is 0. It's always the "natural 0" of any type - `null` for a reference type, 0 for numeric types, U+0000 for `char`, and `false` for `boolean`. See [section 4.12.5 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#96595) for more details.

Note that this is also the default value you get if you just declare an instance/static variable and read it before writing to it.

If you want to allow `id` to be null, you need to make it an `Integer` rather than an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2915285065334004197L;
    transient int a; //Transient Variables are not serialized and returns 0/null after deserialization
    static int b; //Static Variable are not serialized and returns the current/updated value
    int c; //instance variables will be serialized

    public Employee() {

        this.a = 10;
        this.b = 20;
        this.c = 30;
    }
}

After seraialization O/P will be 0 20 30
Now, if you write below code after serialization and before deserialization as below
Employee e = new Employee();
e.a = 5;
e.b = 6;
e.c = 7;
O/P will be 0 6 30
```

Comment: it is better to add some explanation to your answer